# Evaluate an integral in 3D space

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, vector-spaces

Is the integration process following P in Cartesian coordinates:

$$ z = \cos(x^2+1), \qquad     y=1$$

Evaluate

$$  \int_{(0,1,\cos(1))}^{(1,1,\cos(2))}\hat{F}dl$$

Over the integration process P and where

$$ \hat{F} = \tan(x)\hat{a}_{y}$$

I believe it's something that look like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMVGSHTN1nI).... but my cartesian coordinate given are
different... I'm not sure about the parametric of my Cartesian coordinate.

Comment: Is the question clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Parametrize P. In other words, express x, y, z in terms of one variable, the parameter. Hint: one of x,y,z will work as parameter.
2. Differentiate x,y,z with respect to parameter.
3. Plug the parametrization from 1 into F.
4. Take dot product of the results of 2 and 3.
5. Integrate the result of 4 with respect to the parameter.

Had you explained where your difficulty lies, you might have received a more concrete advice.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention my actual difficulty... It's number 1, I know I have to parametrize my function, but I don't really know if I do it correctly. I believe, I have to put under a common variable each coordinates. Something, like x=t, y=1, z= cos(t2+1)... Is that correct?

Comment: @fneron Yes that is correct.